# aws-s3 gem install error- bittorrent.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rubygems, amazon-web-services

Am running build install on an existing project and I get this error:

```
Installing aws-s3 (0.6.2)
Errno::EACCES: Permission-denied -
D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/bittorrent.rb

An error occured while installing aws-s3 (0.6.2) and Bundler cannot
continue, make sure that gem install aws-s3 -v '0.6.2' succeeds before
bundling.
```

I get the same error if I just run "gem install aws-s3 -v '0.6.2'"

Doing this on Windows 7, and I am making sure to run the prompt as
administrator.

Any ideas how to get past this?

Comment: Use a proper OSS-friendly operating system for development. :-p

Comment: Sigh, I know. this is my work computer, no choice. And I can't partition and install Linux b/c of corporate IT requirements.

Comment: Might be worth getting your boss involved - right now, Corporate IT is preventing you from doing your job properly. Virtually everyone putting gems (and Ruby itself) is working on a UNIX-based system, so there are going to be all sorts of edge-case bugs on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

- In your Gemfile or wherever you have specified the gems list and replace source 'https' with this source 'http' otherwise it will keep on asking Make sure that gem install xxx -v 'xxx'' succeeds before bundling.
- Do bundle install or rails new todo